# So I am trying to install isc-dhcp-server, but when I tried installing it, the following errors show

Tags: server, dhcp

```
sudo apt-get install isc-dhcp-server 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies: isc-dhcp-server: Depends: libirs-export161 but it is not installable Recommends: policycoreutils but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Either read `man systemd-dnsmasq` (the modern way) or append `libirs-export161` to your command. Read `man systemd-dnsmasq` in any case. You'll have to move it out of the way if you continue with `isc-dchp-server`.